# Sort all DataTable in Dataset for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datatable

I need to `Sort`  all `DataTables` in mt `Dataset`. I have tried using `DefaultView`, It's sorting my datatable but after the loop the datatable looks same without sorting.

This is what i tried:

```
 For Each Dt As DataTable In AlbumListDs.Tables
   Dt.DefaultView.Sort = "ImageData Asc"
   Dt = DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable
   Dt.AcceptChanges()
   AlbumListDs.AcceptChanges()
 Next
```

Please correct me if i did anything wrong.

Comment: @Steve I can't get you???

Comment: It seems that you try to change the variable returned by the iterator in your loop (dt). This should be catched by the compiler as an error.

Comment: @Steve No it's fully working code. My `AlbumDs` `Dataset` will have 4 Datatable and i need to sort each DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes that you made to the DataTable when inside the loop are local to the element returned by the Iterator of the For Each.

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx)

> **Modifying Collection Elements**. The Current property of the enumerator
>   object is ReadOnly (Visual Basic), and it returns a local copy of each
>   collection element. This means that you cannot modify the elements
>   themselves in a For Each...Next loop. Any modification you make
>   affects only the local copy from Current and is not reflected back
>   into the underlying collection.

So, when you recreate the DataTable with

```
Dt = DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable
```

the new Dt instance is not the same instance contained in the DataSet. And so your changes are lost at the same moment when you loop over another DataTable element.
This is in striking contrast on what you can do in C# where an attempt to change the iterator instance is immediately caught by the compiler and signaled as an error at compile time

Perhaps you could just change the DefaultView sort expression and leave the DataTable in its original order (Surely it will be better for your memory usage). When you need to loop in an ordered way, just use the DataView

```
For Each drv As DataRowView in DataTable.DefaultView
   Console.WriteLine(drv("YourField").ToString())
Next
```

Or use a normal for...loop (BUT IN BACKWARD direction)

```
For x as Integer = AlbumListDs.Tables.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
   Dim dt = AlbumListDs.Tables(x)
   dt.DefaultView.Sort = "ImageData Asc"
   AlbumListDs.Tables.RemoveAt(x)
   AlbumListDs.Tables.Add(dt.DefaultView.ToTable)
Next
AlbumListDs.AcceptChanges
```

Notice that you need to remove the previous table from the collection (Tables is readonly) and then add the new one. This is safer if you loop backward from the end of the collection to the first element to avoid possible indexing errors

Comment: I'm getting erron in this line `AlbumListDs.Tables(x) = dt.DefaultView.ToTable` as `Proerty Item Read Only`

Comment: Yes, sorry it is more complicated that that because you cannot change the DataTable items in that way. I will update the answer.

Comment: It's working good steve. But the DataTable order is rearranged. Is there any idea to fix it?

Comment: You could try to experiment with a loop in the natural order, but I am not sure if you could do this without skipping one or more table when the dataset contains a lot of tables. Or you could use an empty DataSet and add the table from the previuos DataSet in the order that you require.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it in a different way. It might not be the best solution but works for what I needed to do.

```
objReturnDS.Tables(1).DefaultView.Sort = "RowID asc"
                    objReturnDS.Tables(1).DefaultView.ToTable(True)

                    Dim sortedTable = objReturnDS.Tables(1).DefaultView.ToTable(True)
                    objReturnDS.Tables(1).Clear()

                    objReturnDS.Tables(1).Merge(sortedTable)
```

Comment: Hi Mac Chibueze, Thanks for your post it helps me.

Comment: @MidhunKumarSinghAlluru I am glad to hear that it did help you.